# Control cannot fall through from one case label to another

Tags: c#, sql

I've looked around and I've gathered that it means the break is unreachable, but I don't  understand how it's unreachable or what it's trying to reach. The code I get the error on is the following, maybe someone could show me what to add to make the break reachable:

```
#region :buy <item>

case "buy":
    string Item = stringManager.wrapParameters(args, 1);

    if (Item == "bread") 
    {
        int foodfunds;
        int myfood;
        int foodCheck;
        int creditCheck;
        using (DatabaseClient dbClient = Eucalypt.dbManager.GetClient())
            foodfunds = dbClient.getInt("SELECT credits FROM users WHERE name = '" + _Username + "'");
        using (DatabaseClient dbClient = Eucalypt.dbManager.GetClient())
            myfood = dbClient.getInt("SELECT food FROM users WHERE name = '" + _Username + "'");
        if (foodfunds < 10)
        {
            Room.sendData("BK" + "Not enough cash.");
        }
        if (_roomID != 193)
        {
            sendData("BK" + "You must be in the supermarket to buy bread");
        }
        else
        {
            using (DatabaseClient dbClient = Eucalypt.dbManager.GetClient())
                dbClient.runQuery("UPDATE users SET food = food + 1 WHERE name = '" + _Username + "'");
            using (DatabaseClient dbClient = Eucalypt.dbManager.GetClient())
                foodCheck = dbClient.getInt("SELECT food FROM users WHERE name = '" + _Username + "'");
            using (DatabaseClient dbClient = Eucalypt.dbManager.GetClient())
                dbClient.runQuery("UPDATE users SET credits = credits - 10 WHERE name = '" + _Username + "'");
            using (DatabaseClient dbClient = Eucalypt.dbManager.GetClient())
                creditCheck = dbClient.getInt("SELECT credits FROM users WHERE name = '" + _Username + "'");
            Room.sendShout(roomUser, "*Buys a loaf of bread and stashes in bag*");
            Room.sendSaying(roomUser, "(Now have: " + foodCheck + " loaves of bread)");
            Room.sendSaying(roomUser, "(Now have: " + creditCheck + " credits left)");
        }
        if (myfood > 255)
        {
            Room.sendData("BK" + "You cannot carry anymore food!");
        }
        break;
    }
#endregion
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Your indentation is odd but it looks like the `break` is inside the `if`?

Answer (score 6):

That error means that there are some cases in which the `break;` won't get hit.

Specifically, `if (Item == "bread")` isn't true.

Answer (score 1):

Move the `break` outside the last `}`. With your code, if the Item is not 'bread', the `break` is not reached.